# How to open a new tab to the right in Windows Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Without using extensions (Because they interfere with the Groups function in Chrome), how to to open a new tab (or a link in a new tab) **in the background next to the current one** using either keyboard shortcuts or the mouse's wheel button.

Cntl+T opens new tabs at the end of the window and it is an absolute headache to go back to the tab I was using before (Which otherwise I would use Cntl+Shift+T to do so).

I've discovered that right clicking the tab and choosing "New tab to the right" solves the problem, but I've been using the Cntl+T for years, using the mouse is very inconvenient and slow for me now, especially that using Chrome is the most thing I do all day. Isn't there anyway to add a shortcut to this function?

I heard there is a keyboard-shortcut thing on Mac, but I am a Windows user.

Comment: What’s the keyboard shortcut on macOS based on the keys it likely will be easier to figure out the Windows equivalent

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use an extension. Otherwise,
you may create a keyboard shortcut for a new tab to the right,
but it has to typed into the address bar.

Do this :

- Open Chrome *Settings > Search engine*
- Click "Manage search engines and site search"
- Next to "Site search" click "Add"
- Enter the following:

  - *Search engine* : Anything you like, for example "New tab to right"
  - *Shortcut* : The characters to type into the address field, example `xx`
  - *URL* : Enter  `javascript:window.open()`
- Now entering `xx` in the address field will open a new tab to the right.

For further improvement, you may use a macro utility such as
AutoHotKey to create a keyboard shortcut that will position
to the address bar and type these characters for you.

Comment: Chrome extensions will ruin the tab groups sometimes: any group that is not visible in the tab strip (if there are too many tabs to be visible) it will cancel out the non-visible groups. I assume that when chrome restarts, it loads the tabs in order from the left and works it way to the right using the normal shortcut control+T, and the extension forces open-groups-tabs to open next to the next one and disregard the groups, hence keeping some groups empty, and chrome's default action for empty groups is to delete them, this messed up my whole sessions and I am in a MESS.

Comment: This answer is not for an extension - it's for adding a fake "search engine" that open an empty tab instead of searching Google or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do this in the past and there is no built-in way to do this in Chrome. There is a Chrome extension called "Open Tabs Next to Current" I think it is called that can do this.

You can set a keyboard shortcut too via the extension for opening a new tab next to the currently active tab. Click the "Keyboard shortcuts" tab. Then, enter a keyboard shortcut in the "Open new tab next to current tab" field.

Hope that helps its the easiest solution I have found

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-tabs-next-to-current/gmpnnmonpnnmnhpdldahlekfofigiffh

Comment: It is my mistake I didn't clarify my question, I've edited my question:

I need the tab to be opened in the background, and I need it to open links in the same way as well. This extention only opens fresh new tabs and it takes you to it (you lose the focus on the current tab)